# How to convert Binary matrix to Decimal matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

In mat-lab I have Binary 10x10 matrix [image: print screen of mat-lab]

I want to convert this into a 10x10 decimal matrix. How I can do that ?

Edit: r is 10x10 binary matrix.

Comment: What format is `r`? If it's a cell matrix of strings then just use `bin2dec`

Comment: @Dan r is 10x10 binary matrix. Picture that I have put along with the question is snap shot of mat-lab. **bin2dec** I tried but it is not working for matrix. I answered your question ?

Comment: What is a binary matrix in matlab please? Is it a cell array of logical row vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your snapshot, we can infer that you have a *double* type matrix contains only "`1`" and "`0`" as value.

Therefore, I reproduce and solve your case like this:

```
>> r   = [11111010, 11111111; 1010101, 101]
result = cellfun(@(x) bin2dec(num2str(x)), num2cell(r))

r =

    11111010    11111111
     1010101         101


result =

   250   255
    85     5
```

Or, you don't have to use `cellfun()`, you can just use `arrayfun()` without converting array/matrix to cell array, like this:

```
>> r   = [11111010, 11111111; 1010101, 101]
result = arrayfun(@(x) bin2dec(num2str(x)), r)
```

Or, if we assumed you have ***binary*** type (*logical*) cell array, this could be a solution:

```
r      = {[1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0], [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]; [1 0 1 0 1 0 1], [1 0 1]}; %// Double type binary valued cell array
r      = cellfun(@(x) logical(x), r, 'UniformOutput', false);              %// You asserted binary type cell array is given
result = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)( sum(pow2(length(x)-1:-1:0) .* x) ), r, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

---

Used built-in functions: [`cellfun()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), [`bin2dec()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bin2dec.html), [`num2str()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), [`num2cell()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), [`arrayfun()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) and [`cell2mat()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng ... ((:  I've realized working on cell is not as easy as working on array, at least for me. This needs to be acquainted with it.

Comment: Working with cells becomes very limited when you want to try and vectorize your code.  Most of the time you have no choice but to iterate over each cell... which is certainly why putting data into arrays is more suitable.... and yes, you have certainly realized that too :)

Comment: @rayryeng, Exactly!.. Unlike this case, better have proper size of arrays of arrays (: